# Map objects from my Binary Image onto my colour image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I've used the bwconcomp function to find objects in my binary image. I know how to access the numbobjects. I use regionprops for other elements.

My ideal goal is the map the area of them to a colour image. So I can select each individual object on the colour image and compute things on the colour image. I also would like to get the corner pixels of each object for a MBR.

If you could point me in the right direction for creating mask. That would be appreciated :)

Comment: can you tell what kind of objects are you looking for in the image

Comment: connected components. They're strange shapes (not uniform) but bwconcomp has found them and stored them inside the pixelidxlist I just want to know how to extract them and then put them on the colour image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform regionprops with bounding box analysis. You can find the no of objects there. You would also be able to get upper left corner co-ordinates and height and width of that object.

If you are not cropping the original image then you can simply use the same co-ordinates in order to extract your object. If you want to crop, then you can add the offset to the upper-left corner and the same for original image.

Here is one of my coding examples.

```
clear all;
clc;

%convert image into pixel data
im = imread('abc.jpg');
%convert image to binary with edges only
bw = im2bw(im, 0.1);
%show image
imshow(bw);

%identify various boxes present in the image and also calculate their area
stats = regionprops(bw, 'BoundingBox', 'Area');

j=1;

% m is the maximum area i.e. area of entire image
max = 2819982;
for i=2:length(stats)
    if stats(i).Area ~= 1
        if stats(i).Area <= max

            %this would crop image to perticular box
            ans=imcrop(im, stats(i).BoundingBox);

            % here the image is saved as a new file 
            filename = sprintf('Answer_%d.jpg',j);
            imwrite(ans,filename);

            % j is just an incrementor for filename
            j=j+1;

        end
    end
end
```

Here is the image that i worked on:-
[image: abc.jpg]

The goal was to separate each rectangle as image.

Comment: could you give a syntax example of how to extract the object in the colour image? Please

Comment: @user3590937 the example is added in the answer.