# How to Find rectangular region using hough line in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, hough-transform

Edit :

I use this code but did't finded plate region. How do I find the plate ?

This code gives only horizontal lines but I must find vertical and horizontal lines.

---

```
    I  = imread('image.jpg');
    I= rgb2gray(I);
    %I(:,1:2)=0;
    %I(1,:)=0;
    %I(end,:)=0;
    %I(:,end)=0;
    BW = edge(I,'canny');
    %imshow(BW)
    [H,T,R] = hough(BW);
    %{
    imshow(H,[],'XData',T,'YData',R,...
                'InitialMagnification','fit');
    xlabel('\theta'), ylabel('\rho');
    axis on, axis normal, hold on;
    %}
    P = houghpeaks(H, 20,'NHoodSize',[1 1],'threshold',ceil(0.1*max(H(:))));
    lines = houghlines(BW, T, R, P, 'FillGap', 40, 'MinLength', 1);
    %P  = houghpeaks(H,7,'NHoodSize','threshold',ceil(0.4*max(H(:))));
    %lines = houghlines(BW,T,R,P,'FillGap',40,'MinLength',90);
    x = T(P(:,2)); y = R(P(:,1));
    %plot(x,y,'s','color','blue');
    % Find lines and plot them
    figure;
    imagesc(I);hold on;colormap gray;
    axis image; 
    max_len = 0;
    for k = 1:length(lines)
       xy = [lines(k).point1; lines(k).point2];
       % Plot beginnings and ends of lines
       %plot(xy(1,1),xy(1,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','yellow');
       plot(xy(2,1),xy(2,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','red')
       plot(xy(1,1),xy(2,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','blue');
       %plot(xy(2,2),xy(2,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','green');
      plot(xy(:,1),xy(:,2),'LineWidth',2,'Color','green'); %connect red and blue point
     % Determine the endpoints of the longest line segment
       len = norm(lines(k).point1 - lines(k).point2);
       if ( len > max_len)
          max_len = len;
          xy_long = xy;
       end
    end
```

---

This part draws connect red and blue point. How to connect blue blue point and red red point ? If I can it , I find plate area.

`% Plot beginnings and ends of lines
           %plot(xy(1,1),xy(1,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','yellow');
           plot(xy(2,1),xy(2,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','red')
           plot(xy(1,1),xy(2,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','blue');
           %plot(xy(2,2),xy(2,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','green');
          plot(xy(:,1),xy(:,2),'LineWidth',2,'Color','green'); %connect red and blue point`

then , Probably   `lines = houghlines(BW, T, R, P, 'FillGap', 40, 'MinLength', 90);` this part change.

[image: Input pic]
[image: Output pic]

Comment: I think the most easiest way to detect a square box is by using regionprops() command. An available answer is here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27415415/map-objects-from-my-binary-image-onto-my-colour-image/27419778#27419778     But if you still want to use hough line only, then the most easy solution is "Rotate image by 90 degree. Find weather same end points are present or not. Use +-10 pixels as margin."

Comment: I must be hough line ; then I rotate image , this code finded vertical lines.I want to vertical and horizontal line. But I didn't draw together.

Comment: I hope,  explain the problem,  clearly

Comment: @Adrian: Yes this is clearer, thank you. One of your problems here is that `houghpeaks` finds a lot of longer lines before it finds the vertical lines you need. If you drop the threshold down and try again, does it eventually find the verticals you want (amongst a lot of noise I expect)? There may be other approaches you could take - I think it is worth explaining the range of images you are expecting to process. For example, if the vehicle is always centred, then you can search for two parallel near-horizontal lines close to where you expect them, and use that to define a region.